# maximising the angle $\theta$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

OK, suppose I have two points in cartesian coordinate system, say $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2)$. I have a line as well, that is, for simplicity
$$y=mx$$
Assuming that 
$$y_1\neq mx_1,y_2\neq mx_2$$
I need to find the point $A$ on the line so that the angle $PAQ$ is maximum. So I assume that point is $A(h,k)$. So the slope of $PA$ is ${k-y_1 \over h-x_1}$, and that of $QA$ is ${k-y_2 \over h-x_2}$. Then I find $\theta$ (the angle $PAQ$) by the inverse tangent way
$$\theta=arctan({m_1-m_2 \over 1+m_1m_2 })$$
For the maxima, I differentiate this angle with respect to either $h$ or $k$ using the fact that $k=mh$ and put it to zero. Then all of that and the answer comes out. I plug that back and get a value. But the range of $arctan$ is from $[{-\pi \over 2},{\pi \over 2}]$. I do not think my way will work for obtuse angles. Is there any other way? P.S.Just give me a hint.

I apologize if this is too "elementary". Diagram-
[image]

Comment: so it means that you can calculate slope and  intercept  from this two point,maximum angle  can be  calculate  easily ,maximum is theta or $\pi-theta$

Comment: By **line**, what exactly do you mean? $x$-axis ? $y$-axis?

Comment: @Inceptio: I mean the line $y=mx$ that passes through the origin.

Comment: Well, for maximizing the angle, the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and  $(x_1,y_1)$ tends to $(x,y)$ (But do not lie on the line $y=mx$). Where did you find the problem? What's the source?

Comment: If points don't lie on the line, then angle doesn't have max. It has sup though.

Comment: @Inceptio: Actually this is a modified problem. The question had details of the actual points and worked by finding the derivate of arctan thing, because the angle was acute. I just asked if a similar thing would go in for obtuse.

Comment: @AshishGaurav: If it's acute, the angle between the points is tending to $90^ \circ$. But here, the angle tends to $\pi$. And about arc $\tan$, you can use the hint by dato.

Comment: 2Kaster -- sure it has a max. That's what the suggested formulae give.

Comment: Hint: think a bit harder about what "the angle between two lines" means. Using your $arctan$ formula, you will have trouble calculating the angle between *any* two lines. Once you have sorted this out, your method will work.

Comment: A geometric hint: you get the maximum angle when the moving point lies on a circle passing through $P$ and $Q$ and tangent to the given line. Using this approach, you don't need any calculus, just simple trig/geometry.

Comment: @bubba: Is that a standard result? Can you prove it?

Comment: It's not a standard result, but it's based on well-known geometric facts. A chord subtends the same angle at all points on a circle. Obviously the angle will get bigger as the circle radius gets smaller. I expect I could prove all this. But it would be messy, and your original reasoning will work, anyway, if you take a bit more care with angles, as I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(x_c,m\,x_c)$ be the point on the line.
By law of cosines
$$\theta=\arccos \bigg(\frac{q^2+p^2-c^2}{2\, p\, q}\bigg)$$
where
$$p=\sqrt{(x_2-x_c)^2+(y_2-m\,x_c)^2}$$
$$q=\sqrt{(x_1-x_c)^2+(y_1-m\,x_c)^2}$$
$$c=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
If you differentiate wrt $x;_c$ and solve for $x_c$ in $\frac{d\theta}{dx_c}=0$ set of solution
$$x_c=\frac{x_1\,y_2-x_2\,y_1}{m\,x_1-m\,x_2-y_1+y_2}$$
$$x_c=\frac{(1+m^2)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)-\sqrt{(1+m^2)(mx_1-y_1)(mx_2-y_2)\big((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\big)}}{(1+m^2)(m(x_1-x_2)-y_1+y_2)}$$
$$x_c=\frac{(1+m^2)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)+\sqrt{(1+m^2)(mx_1-y_1)(mx_2-y_2)\big((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\big)}}{(1+m^2)(m(x_1-x_2)-y_1+y_2)}$$
If you run the second derivative test you will see that max occurs at (it depends on relative location of P, Q and the line)
$$x_c=\frac{(1+m^2)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)-\sqrt{(1+m^2)(mx_1-y_1)(mx_2-y_2)\big((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\big)}}{(1+m^2)(m(x_1-x_2)-y_1+y_2)}$$

Comment: So, what's your hint?

Comment: Maybe I got the hint- arccos has the range of $[0,\pi]$ and that can return a maximum value which might be obtuse.